# How to configure Phantomjs driver to execute in linux machine using java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying load phantom js like below.

```
File file = new File("src/test/resources/phantomjs-linux");             
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

When i execute this in linux machine gets below exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /home/tomcat-jenkins/workspace/pitchIT/pitchIT-services/src/test/resources/phantomjs-linux
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS(PhantomJSDriverService.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:89)
    at com.astrazeneca.als.pitchIT.util.BDDUtilities.doInit(BDDUtilities.java:69)
    at com.astrazeneca.als.pitchIT.util.BDDUtilities.getDriver(BDDUtilities.java:33)
    at com.astrazeneca.als.pitchIT.controller.PitchITHomepageSteps.an_browser_win
```

Answer (score 0):

but if you want to have it with absolute path

File phantomJSBinary = new File("path" + File.separator + "to" + File.separator + "phantomjs");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantomJSBinary.getAbsolutePath());